# EXCEL - Conditional formatting to return cell colour and text entry when cell is a particular colour

Tags: excel

I am working on a spreadsheet where conditional formatting is set up based on the selection of a drop down list which turns the cell grey in colour.  I also need it to enter the text "NA" when the cell changes to grey.

The current formula in place is

`=ISNUMBER(SEARCH("LTD",B7))=TRUE`

and then cell eg B17 turns grey

How can I construct it to also make cell `B17` show `NA`?

Comment: You can not use conditional format to modify the value or formula in a cell.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try `=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("LTD",B7)),"NA")` in B17.